# BQ Error: references position X, but line starting at position:_contains only X columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I am well aware of what a good question on SO looks like, and I'm sorry I cannot share the data generating the error, so yes this is a bad question. I am however getting an extremely cryptic error message:

```
 'Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 42, but line starting at position:636 contains only 42 columns.'}, 'errors': [{'reason': 'invalid', 'location': 'XXXX', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 42, but line starting at position:636 contains only 42 columns.'}, {'reason': 'invalid', 'message': 'Error while reading data, error message: CSV processing encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 6285; errors: 1; max bad: 0; error percent: 0'}], 'state': 'DONE'}}
```

The error message seems to say that a particular row of mine has 42 columns BUT the table (I've predefined the schema not auto-generated) expects 42... which doesn't make sense. Any insight into what is occurring? I looked at row 6285 and nothing looks incorrect to me. I don't know what position 636 means? Row 6285 doesn't even have 500 characters on it. Maybe that's the problem? Something to do with bad newlines or something?

Comment: I have seen similar issue at my work, if your table is being updated from a file then better to check the rows in the file. Also try to safe_cast the fields to ignore the error. Could you check this.

Answer (score 0):

"Position" in the BigQuery CSV import errors refer to byte offsets from the start of the file. Therefore "line starting at position:636" refers to the line starting 636 bytes from the beginning of the file.

Regarding the error message itself: `references column position 42, but line starting at position:636 contains only 42 columns`. This is saying that the schema expects a column "42" (zero indexed?) but there aren't enough columns at this line.

If this is expected, you may consider enabling the `--allow_jagged_rows` option, which will treat missing columns at the end of a row as NULL instead of error.

Comment: How are you setting the schema? Does the first line contain 43+ columns?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened here, after hours trying to solve it,  I found  a basic error, I was using an old bash script to load CSV files into BQ and forgot to change the field separator, check it